# Why does the for loop behave this way?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

```
 #python_code
    a_list=[1,2,3,4]
    for item in a_list:
      print(a_list[item])


> #Output:
>     2
>     3
>     4
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
>         print(a_list[item])
>     IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am trying to learn python and was going over some tutorials when i came over this. Can anyone explain what is happening here?
The first item doesn't get printed. I wonder why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the first value of 'item' is the first element of a_list which is '1'.
print(a_list[item]) implies print(a_list[1]), which is '2'. (The array starts with zero, so a_list[0]=1)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. I am just trying to strengthen my basics.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this :

```
# python_code
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for item in a_list:
   print(item)
```

Because in your code :

```
a_list=[1,2,3,4]
    for item in a_list:
      print(a_list[item])
```

This is will iterate like a_list[1], a_list[2], a_list[3], a_list[4] but array indexing starts from 0 so a_list[4] will be out of index because last index should be the array length-1 for your code to work. In your case a_list[3] will be the last element of your array i.e 4

Comment: I appreciate your response. I know that printing 'item' would have worked here. What i don't understand is that if i index it using a_list[item], the first element doesn't get printed. What's the logic here?

Comment: that is because the first element in your array is 1 and a_list[1] is 2 so your 1 is not getting printed. You can accept the answer if its useful